# Why does grep -a output to console?

Tags: windows, bash, windows-7, grep, cygwin

When doing `grep -a 5 "SEARCHSTRING" FILE.txt`, `grep` seems to print the searching of the file to the console in real-time, which I find both useful and cool. However, when simply doing `grep "SEARCHSTRING" FILE.txt`, or `grep -i -n --color -C 5 "SEARCHSTRING" FILE.txt`, I get the usual blinking cursor while it's processing the file.

Why does `grep -a` output to console while searching a file, and how can I replicate that behaviour without using the `-a` option?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that your multiple questions about `grep` are not about programming, and it seems you have not read carefully the manual of grep. 
From `man grep` I see:

```
  -a, --text
          Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent  to
          the --binary-files=text option.
```

So it is NOT redirecting the output,and the default is still console.
There is no option, that I am aware, that delays the output.

Additional note:
`grep -a 5 "SEARCHSTRING" FILE.txt` means open inputs in binary mode and search for strings `5` in files `SEARCHSTRING` and `File.txt`; so you will have more matches than `grep "SEARCHSTRING" FILE.txt` where you are asking instead for `SEARCHSTRING` in `File.txt` . May be this is the reason why you see immediate output and delayed one ? In the first case you have likely much more matches. You can verify it with

```
grep -a 5 "SEARCHSTRING" FILE.txt |wc -l 
grep -i "SEARCHSTRING" FILE.txt |wc -l
```

and compare the numbers of matches. `wc -l` counts the number of lines

Comment: If we're employing such a narrow definition of programming, then the [*many* bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grep) questions already highly-rated on SO would also be off-topic. I posted in SO because there's a long history of such questions, even if they're aren't considered programming in the strictest sense of the term.

Comment: Off-topicness aside, this doesn't seem to answer the question. I've read the documentation for the `-a` switch and many others more times than I can count, but I'm still not entirely clear on what exactly it does and what makes it output to console when other options don't.

Comment: Asking 3 times about `grep` in the same day is not about programming, is about lacking fundamental base ground. `grep` default is to output the matching lines of the input (file or standard input) to standard output. The `-a` option does not change the standard output. May be you should try first some tutorial like `http://www.uccs.edu/~ahitchco/grep/` to understand the concepts.

Comment: With respect, I'm failing to see what logical bearing the amount of questions I ask has to do with the off-topicness of a question. Each question I ask stands alone, and the off-topicness of each one should be decided relative to its content, not my other questions. As already demonstrated, there is plenty of precedent for on-topic `bash` and `grep` questions on SO. As for tutorials and documentation, I've read and followed plenty, but none of them explain why `-a` prints to console and other options do not (and as of yet, neither have you) hence the reason I'm on SO asking this question.

Comment: Do you mean immediate output versus delayed one ? From my side I see no difference in time for output to console using `-a` and/or any other flag. Both are almost immediate.

Comment: So all this time you've been insisting the question is off-topic and you're not even sure what I'm asking? I edited the question to make it clearer, but it was already pretty clear what I was asking from the first half of the original question. I was talking about output *while searching* the file was in progress, not the usual expected output.

Comment: Never mind anyway. Your edit to the question is right - it's processing everything after `-a` as a search pattern and outputting it as it comes, which gave me the impression that it was the real-time progress of the search. Do you know of any way to make a file search behave that way? So I can see all of the strings that grep is processing as it searches through the file, before it outputs the results of the search?